# How can I improve the alignment of my TextView?

Tags: android, layout, alignment, textview

[image]

Right-most textview is causing some alignment issues. I'm not sure how I can alleviate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Layout Width` on the right-most textview to a hard-coded values such as 100dip and set the `Gravity` to `right`.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using `LinearLayout` you could use `weight` to set width of all `TextView`'s in a row